# Using "besides" to add extra information

Tags: adverbs, sentence-structure

I wrote:

> However, XSLT power may be excessive for a simple web scarping task, besides that it requires expertise knowledge.

However, I've mostly seen *Beside* is used to start a new sentence. I want to know did I use it correctly in this sentence?

What are other alternatives to add this extra information to this sentence?

Comment: "Besides that" is equivalent to "In addition to that" (where **that** is a demonstrative pronoun referring back to the idea expressed in the previous clause) and it introduces a new independent clause.    ".... scraping task. Besides that, it requires...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Besides that* is not a conjunction; it doesn't conjoin two clauses. Rather, it's an adverbial, modifying the clause that it's a part of.

So you can't say "X, besides that Y"; instead, you could say one of these:

- "X. Besides that, Y."
- "X, and besides that, Y."
- "X; besides that, Y."

In your case, though, I'd suggest a simple *and*:

> However, XSLT power may be excessive for a simple web scraping task, and it requires specific expertise.

(Note: I've also corrected the spelling of "scraping", and replaced the incorrect *"expertise knowledge" with "specific expertise", which I think is what you meant.)